# The command 'android' failed

Tags: android, apache, cordova

I've read this: [Cordova and setting Android using command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20080325/cordova-and-setting-android-using-command-line)
 and that [How to add android to cordova platform? PATH error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17975421/how-to-add-android-to-cordova-platform-path-error?rq=1) and generally speaking whole documentation. I've added both 'platform-tool' and 'tool' paths, installed android 4.4 and I'm still getting the error from the tittle when I'm trying `cordova platform add android` to my current project ( in cmd and in netbeans ).

The only thing I haven't done is adding `java` and `ant` to path. I was trying with `;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%ANT_HOME%\bin` but still those commands aren't recognizable.

What else can I do?

**EDIT:**

I've added java and ant to PATH. This is what I get in cmd:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\mobile_maps>cordova platform add android
[Error: The command `android` failed. Make sure you have the latest Android SDK
installed, and the `android` command (inside the tools/ folder) added to your pa
th. Output: ]
```

**Second EDIT:**

i also get `'xcopy' is not recognized as an internal or external command` even though I've added  `%SystemRoot%\System32; %SystemRoot%; %SystemRoot%\System32\wbem;%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0` . I really don't know what else I can do..

Comment: Did you use the control panel to add entries to the path?

Comment: I clicked right mouse button on my computer -> properties -> advanced -> environmental variables.

Comment: Write full paths in there, not using %:s

Comment: @Mati, please post your full console output

Answer (score 0):

usually this happens when:
1. Java is not installed
2. Java is not exported (no JAVA_HOME env variable) or paths are wrong
3. only 64bit version of Java is installed

to fix install 32bit support on your system.

and (as comments below) relog in Windows to environment changes take effect.

Comment: well 1. java is installed 2. paths are good ( recognizable in cmd ) 3. just installed 32bit ver. and still not working.

Comment: what system are you running?

Comment: I assume windows. Have you restarted/relog. Windows doesn't pickup vars until relog.